# How to get the accurate mouse cursor index position in a text file

Tags: python, notepad++, text-editors

I have a large text file that I'm importing into a python script as a string using the following code.

```
from pathlib import Path

file = Path('edits.txt').read_text(encoding='UTF8')
```

I need to be able to capture/print a certain paragraph in that text file, so I need to know the position of the character where the paragraph starts, and where it ends, and pass those indexes over to python as string slices e.g `print(file[100:200])`

for example, to copy the following paragraph, I'm setting the mouse cursor right before it begins and using Notepad++ `Ctrl-g`, select offset, and capture the offset number.

Notepad++ screenshot:
[image: notepad++ screenshot]

in our case here, the offset at the beginning is 47997 and at the end is 48715, but when I do `print(file[47997:48715])` I get a different part of the file.

the file includes Unicode characters, but I'm using UTF8 encoding in Notepad ++ and reading the file as UTF8 as well in python.

my question here is, how do I get the correct offset in notepad++ (or any other text editor that you can suggest)?

edit:
I think the problem lies in the Unicode characters, — in "us—when" for example is equivalent to â€” when I change encoding from UTF8 to ASNI and the offset counts 3 characters, probably python treats it as a single character and that's when the offset is missed up

Comment: Have you checked to see if the offsets include EOL markers?

Comment: Why are you using Notepad++ to define the begin/end of a paragraph? Why don't you use Python to do the job? How a paragraph is defined?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, I believe the offset takes EOL markets into consideration. I've also tried to subtract the previous line number from the offset but that did not give me an accurate position as well.

Comment: @Toto there is no pattern to define a paragraph, it's just a block of text that I randomly select from the text file. I don't want to use python to detect where a paragraph starts and ends (using a few words from the paragraph and regex or find()) because I'd be doing this a lot and I thought maybe just knowing the correct offset and passing it to python as a string slice is much easier.

Comment: @DavidPostill I think the problem lies in the Unicode characters, — in "us—when" for example is equivalent to â€” when I change encoding to ASNI and the offset counts 3 characters, probably python treats it as a single character and that's when the offset is missed up